# Node connecting to Mongodb in my VPS with port 27017, no if I change the port

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vps

I've got a Digital Ocean VPS, and followed their tutorial:
[link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-node-js-to-a-mongodb-database-on-a-vps)
It's working the app.js and connecting to the database.
Here is the code of the apps file:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, format = require('util').format;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log("successfully connected to the database");
    }
    db.close();
});
```

But if I change the port 127.0.0.1:27017  to 127.0.0.1:3500  the one I want to connect, it's not working.
Here is my ufw

```
ufw allow 22/tcp
ufw allow 3500/tcp
ufw allow 80/tcp
ufw allow 27017/tcp
```

Any help?
Thank you

Comment: What's the error that gets thrown? Have you changed the port in your MongoDB collection? The connect line only refers to the database, if you want to connect to it through a browser or other means you'll need to set up some sort of library to accept the connection.

Comment: True.  I forgot to change de mongod port, once I have changed there I can connect. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, you did a bad thing. You opened MongoDB to whole world. If your node.js app is on the same server with MongoDb, then no reasons to open 27017 & 3500 for internet. Close these ports ASAP.

Why do you think that you changed mongoDb port? Please show mongoDb config file with port configuration row. Also after you changed the mongodb config file it requires restart mongodb servic/daemon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just learnt what you wrote. I'm on a test server, reading a lot and learning. If my node app and my mongo db are on the same server they can connect directly. I hadn't changed my mongod.conf file